# Retrieve info from many-to-many relationship in django temaplate

Tags: django, django-templates, many-to-many, django-views

I am creating a blog and have a many-to-many relationship between the posts and categories.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    body = RichTextField(config_name='blog')
    slug = models.SlugField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I am trying to retrieve the the list of categories associated to an individual post within the template so I can display those category titles at the bottom of the post.

Here is the template code which displays the posts properly but not the categories.

```
{% for post in blog_posts %}

            <div class="post">
                <div class="date">
                    {{post.published_date|date:"M"}}
                    <span class="day">{{post.published_date|date:"d"}}</span>
                    <span>{{post.published_date|date:"Y"}}</span>
                </div>
                    <div class="entry">
                        <div class="page-header">
                            <h2 class="post-title"><a href="{% url blog_post post.id post.slug %}">{{post.title}}</a></h2>
                        </div>
                        <blockquote>
                            <p><strong>{{post.subtitle}}</strong></p>
                        </blockquote>
                        <p>{{post.body|safe}}</p>
                        <div class="well well-small">
                          <i class="icon-th-list "></i> Categories:LIST CATEGORIES HERE 
                        </div>
                    </div> <!--entry div-->
            </div><!--post div-->
{% endfor %}
```

Does anyone have thoughts on how I could retrieve the categories for a specific post? I greatly appreciate the time and expertise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the categories with this

```
{% for category in post.categories.all %}
    {{ category.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

I also recommend adding `.prefetch_related('categories')` to the queryset in your view to reduce the number of sql queries.

Comment: Worked perfect! I'll read up on prefetch_related and add that to my queryset as well. Thanks for the help.